# Corruption in backup but valid checksum

Tags: backup, sql-server-2019, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

We have corruption in one of our full backups but I can't find an explanation how it happened. The server is a SQL Server 2019 Enterprise edition (CU17) with 5 databases in an AG. The backups are taken on the primary with checksum and the backups are verified with `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` afterwards.
No errors are triggered so far.

Restoring the backup on another server succeeds without any error. But after a while we are getting `Error 824`:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
> pageid (expected 1:1400364408; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read
> of page (1:1400364408) in database ID 6 at offset 0x000a6efbaf0000 in
> file xxxx

Running `DBCC CHECKDB` on the restored database shows that page 1400364408 (PFS page) is corrupt (incorrect page ID in its page header).
We then restored the same backup to several different servers and always the same error on the same page was triggered.

Our first idea was corruption on the primary so we ran `DBCC CHECKDB` but no errors were found. Our next suspect is the backup device.

But if the backup device caused the corruption shouldn't this be detected by the checksum validation during the restore or the verification process?
We also thought there was a bad memory chip on the primary but then `DBCC CHECKDB` should detect the corrupt page on the primary.

Does anybody has another explanation how a backup can get corrupted but still have valid checksums and the source database has no errors during consistency checks?

Comment: `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` doesn' verify the whole database. Which version and edition of SQL Server is the server where you are restoring?

Comment: @Charlieface: We are restoring to multiple SQL Server 2019 Enterprise instances. If there is an I/O error I thought RESTORE VERIFYONLY would trigger an invalid checksum error.

Comment: Like I said `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` doesn't do `CHECKDB`, it just verifies the checksum. Unless the corruption started in the backup then it won't find it. You don't have a checksum issue, you have alogical incosistency. There may have been an issue with the original database in that PFS page, which has since disappeared, Have you taken a new backup and tried that?

Comment: I didn't know that the logical inconsistency could disappear, I'll take a new full backup and check it. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: If the error was on, say, a statistics page that got recomputed, or an index page that got reindexed, or a data page that got deleted, etc. etc. then it could absolutely disappear.  I'd see if I could do some hardware checks, too.